# How to pass Quicksight analysis parameters to a control that has a list?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

In AWS Quicksight I have an analysis with two datasets: dataset 1 is used for the graphics and dataset2 is used for the controls. In the analysis I have two parameters: tenant and userId that take variable values ​​depending on what is passed in the embedded url. I need the list that I have in the controls to be filtered by those parameters. I cannot pass the parameter to dataset2 because if I do, it stays with the preset values ​​and the dataset does not become dynamic.